# Trying to get 3 monitors on Ubuntu 13, max combined resolution is 4096x4096

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, display

I have a Dell machine running Ubuntu 13.10 (I think), with a PCIe video card with 256 MB of RAM and a DisplayLink USB video card with 256 MB of RAM. On the PCIe card I have two monitors, both at 1600x1200, and on the USB card I have a 1280x1024 monitor.

The DisplayLink monitor is recognized, but I can't enable it. When I try to enable the monitor, I get these errors, one after the other:

```
The selected configuration for displays could not be applied
required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(4480, 1200), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(4096, 4096)

Failed to apply configuration: %s
GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gnome_2drr_2derror_2dquark.Code3: required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(4480, 1200), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(4096, 4096)
```

From what I gather, Ubuntu is treating the two display adapters as one, and the specs can't support a combined resolution of more than 4096x4096. Is there any way to increase the max combined resolution to what I need?

In case it matters I'm using the GNOME Classic Shell.

If there are any solutions, could they be explained in a simple manner? I'm pretty new to Ubuntu.